# Installing Xamarin Studio on windows

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have visual studio 2015 with xamarin but i want to install the xamarin studio IDE . In fact, in the official website of xamarin the din't provide you to download the xamarin studio only without downloading the xamarin platform. I have all the other softwares that the platform gives so i want only to install the IDE with no GTK# and no Android SDK and other things, only the xamarin studio IDE. Please if you have any idea about that write it in an answer, and if this possible tell me too. Thanks a lot

Comment: Xamarin Studio for Windows doesn't exist any more (that happened after the question was asked).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Download and install this: 
http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Windows/XamarinStudio-5.9.5.9-0.msi

It installs Xamarin Studio only.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the updated version here 
http://www.monodevelop.com/download/

Comment: That works fine! Also version 6+ available as opposed to accepted answer